# How to Download zip file from opensubtitle.org using requests or scrapy

Tags: scrapy, python-requests, python-3.6

I have the zip file download url, link are below:
https://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/sub/7790586/vrf-f5760bc3.
I made a request for this URL with the required headers and still I can't download the zip file. It gets redirected to old movie page else download unrelated zip file content. I know there is API available but i need this to be done by script, not by API or selenium.

I tried in both request and scrapy get method still I can't download the correct zip file.

```
headers = { 
"authority": "dl.opensubtitles.org","Connection": "keep-alive", 
"user-agent":user_agent, 
"accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3","accept-encoding": "gzip,deflate,br","accept-language": "en-IN,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8","referer": movie_url,'upgrade-insecure-requests':'1'}

requests.get(url,headers=headers)
```

Comment: what is your code for actually writing to file?\

Answer (score 2):

```
with requests.get(url, stream=True) as res:
    with open('test.zip', 'wb') as f:
        for chunk in res.iter_content(chunk_size=1024): #you can also change the chunk size
             if chunk: # filter out 
                 f.write(chunk)
```